# In CXF jax-rs endpoint how to use accepts

Tags: rest, jax-rs, cxf, versioning

I have a simple question 
If we look at http://barelyenough.org/blog/2008/05/versioning-rest-web-services/
which  clearly tells us that we can use accepts for versioning.

something  like this.

now when i  use the same in my endpoint as below

```
@Path("/myendpoing")
@Produces({"application/xml","application/json"})
@Consumes({"application/vnd.mycompany.external-v1.0+xml","application/vnd.mycompany-v1.0+json"})
```

it compiles fine
but when i give a call to this endpoint with  Accept header , it gives me 406 , Not Acceptable response.

Any pointers with CXF implementation.

Also hopefully I can get the interceptors for version mismatch , or version validation etc.

Any link to the  solution please.

Regards

Comment: What accept header, exactly, did you send it?

Comment: I have tried to add Accepts header to application/vnd.mycompany.external-v1.0+xml but it does not work,   but application/xml works fine with the above mentioned code too.

Comment: You still don't reveal what is in the accept header or what version of CXF. In general, the cxf user mailing list is prone to be helpful.

Comment: ok may be it be a issue? i am using version 2.6.0 . I am sending accepts header as "application/xml" as it does not accepts anything else

Comment: sorry version 2.3.3 for this project. Let me upgrade it to latest version and see if it affects the how i accept the input.